# Battery high voltage

Tags: electrical, power, power-outlet, multimeter

I measured my "cigar socket / outlet" with a multimeter. Instead of 12v it had 19v. Is this normal? Is it my voltage regulator, alternator, battery that has problems?

Car: 
Peugeot 307, 2.0 XSI 2003
The 12v "cigar socket / outlet" is off when my key is turned off, and on when I turn it on.

Additional information: 
Battery is almost 1 month old. Mechanic replaced it.

> ```
> Voltage car off with key not inserted
> Battery -  12v socket
> 16,67v     0v
>
> Voltage car off with key turned 2/3 steps
> Battery -      12v socket
> not tested     18,2v
>
> Voltage car on
> Battery -  12v socket
> 20v        20v
>
> Voltage car, airco, headlights on
> Battery  - 12v socket
> 20v        20v
> ```

Comment: Did you check the voltage output at the alternator as well?

Comment: I guess I should have first asked if the car was running or not (with key not just in the acc position) when tested?

Comment: I've added additional information in my question above. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your voltmeter is working properly?

Comment: @Paul I am going to the mechanic tomorrow. I think and hope my multimeter is busted. Tested it with my power supply and it gave +2 volts readings. Still the car battery would be too high, even with +2 volts wrongly added volts..

Comment: It may be off by a percentage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Went to the mechanic, and the voltage looked good at 14,4v +- when everything (car, airco, lights, radio) were on. Looks like my multimeter is busted. Need to buy a new 9v battery for my multimeter to test if that fixes the offset, or I'll try to calibrate my multimeter.

Anyways, always test with another multimeter if in doubt.

Comment: You can also test on a known source, which is a procedural requirement for professional electricians.

Comment: Yes, I did that and it gave wrong values. Even with a new battery + some calibration it still has big differences. Time for some a new multimeter.