# Rear camera screen flickering

Tags: camera, backup-camera

https://youtu.be/c4g_W9xNboQ video of it flickering.
I've tested the output voltage of the 12v socket, and it's around 20v! Question about that here; [Battery high voltage](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/16154/car-12v-socket-outlet-has-higher-voltage-19-volts-is-this-normal?noredirect=1#comment21954_16154) (multimeter was busted, volts are normal)

Whenever I am in neutral, or geared my screen flickers. It should only turn itself on when I am in reverse. In reverse, the display turns on fine and I can see the rear camera view, but when not in reverse, it starts flickering randomly. 
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is this an aftermarket reverse camera? If factory installed, what kind of vehicle (year/make/model). If aftermarket, what is the model of the reverse camera?

Comment: I bought it from ebay, china. The camera and screen both work great. I installed them myself. Only problem is, that my screen flashes like the video whenever the camera was off. I tested the screen with my 12v pc power supply and my canon camera, and it worked, and when I disconnected the camera, the screen did not flicker. I tested it in my car, and it seems to have stopped with flickering. Have to test longer to see if the problem is gone

Comment: Looks like the video cable (most likely some RCA analog crap, I doubt there's anything digital in this cheap camera system) is either damaged, the connectors aren't plugged correctly or is picking up some noise.

Comment: It was caused by an blown light bulb, which caused the + and - of where I connected the rear camera to have somewhere between 1 and 4 volts, just enough to give my rear camera juice to let my screen think it wanted to turn on.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I was wondering if it's because I hooked the two power wires together. For the mirror and the receiver. It's still 107 in AZ so I'll check it later. Anybody any thoughts about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so here is what was causing my screen to flicker. I took out my rear lights where I have connected the camera and saw that the reverse light was blown. I measured the the + and - leads and without any light bulb inserted into the reverse light slot, the + and - had something between 1 and 4 volts, multimeter is inaccurate by +- 2volts. This is of course not enough for the camera to fully turn on, but was enough for it to receive some noise and let the screen think the rear camera wanted to turn on.

Anyways, put a new lightbulb in and the problem is gone. Tested if it definitely was the light bulb, and took it out again, and the screen started flickering again. Whenever I put in the lightbulb, there is no volts on the + and -, but whenever I take it out, there is.

So my problem is solved. Just had to replace the damaged light bulb

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem by running the positive wire from the reversing light to the monitor (as well as the camera)

Answer (score 1):

the wife was having a problem with her Dodge Journey, she kinda touches other vehicles when she is backing up. I bought a wireless backup camera system and installed it but the monitor flashed constantly so I disconnected it and ordered a new TX &RX . They are about $15 so no biggy, it came in and the same thing happened, hmmm must be the monitor right, so $20 for another monitor. Wire it up and damit the same thing.  I hit the internet looking for a solution,and there is nothing. so I start looking into the monitor and the wireless parts. Hmmm the wireless operates at 2.4 GHz, wait a second almost everything today works at 2.4 even the Journey bluetooth is 2.4. So the problem is the RX is to sensitive and is starting to respond to these random signals and starts the power on the monitor then shuts off. So the solution was to run the RX power from the backup lights 12 volts. It took an afternoon to run the wire, they put the backup lights in the tailgate which just made it so much more fun. I got it working now and no flashing screen, the Journey has this overhead consul with a sunglass holder, but the tiny plastic catch always breaks and the thing is always open. Neat thing it is just the size to hold a 3x5 monitor. SB is used to driving with it open so it works fine it is just above the rearview mirror so no blocking out any spots. FUN FUN FUN.

Comment: And this, folks, is why *digital* wireless protocols are better. Though I'd love to see what happens when you're near another car with the same system, trying to back up at the same time.